# Problem with internet connection

Tags: windows, windows-vista, networking, wireless-networking, internet

I am working on Windows Vista. I have got two internet connections, one is WiFi connection with high speed and other is mobile network connection.

There is a very strange problem I am getting. When I connect to WiFi connection I an not able to surf internet (actually not all the sites). I am able to search on Google but when I click on any link in the search list it does not open. But I am able to surf all the pages in google.com domain and also all the pages in stackoverflow domain. But I am not able to go to page `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2`

But When I am connected by my mobile network. I am able to surf any site.

Can you please tell me what might me the problem with my settings.

Comment: What does "it does not open" mean?

Comment: see this comment: http://superuser.com/questions/116942/cant-access-certain-web-sites-reset-router-any-ideas/116969#116969

Comment: Probably conflict between the two connections. Disable (in cp) one while using the other.

Comment: Acually it does not open the page. Situation with wifi connection is still like that. I have tried to work with same wifi and UBUNTU OS. It works like charm, no problem. I did tried deleting the wireless connection from and adding again, but does not help, I tried to reset, disable, firewall and antivirus program. But event then it does not wok. I can open some site i does not want. But the site i am looking for is not opening.

Answer (score 0):

Could be your DNS settings.  Try connecting to the repo1.maven.org site site using "http://38.97.124.18/maven2" using your wifi connection.  If that works, then the DNS in your wifi connection is not working (probably set to the wrong DNS server or just a bad DNS server).  Some sites might still work in your wifi because the DNS lookups for those sites might be cached locally.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried removing the proxy settings that are present in the Tools --> Internet Options.

There should not be any proxy or connection settings. Mostly this happens when you use a laptop provided by your office. Office laptops are configured in such a way that they use the proxy for Interent and bypass the local office web applications. So give a try removing the proxy settings if any, and also check the Properties of Wireless network. It should be automatically configured. If manually configured, try removing this.