# Unable to reach my own externally hosted website I was able to reach yesterday

Tags: networking, dns, blocking

I'm unable to reach my site, https://www.inagalaxyfarfarawry.com, at home via laptop, phone, and Firestick. I'm in Canada when I can't connect, though I'm still in Canada when I can connect (please read below) through my work laptop and my phone (again, but with data turned on and WiFi turned off).

Here's the situation:

I was able to reach this site yesterday, but since trying to get it today, I've been unable. I've tried on:

- my home computer (Windows 10). Its browsers (Firefox and Edge) both time out after a minute or two.
- my phone (Android Galaxy A8). Its browser (Samsung Internet 10.2.00.53) doesn't connect.
- my Amazon Firestick, which doesn't connect through the Firefox app I downloaded onto it

I also can't go to a command prompt and ping the site. I get:

```
Pinging inagalaxyfarfarawry.com [144.217.20.186] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 144.217.20.186:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

Furthermore, I can't even go to the web host's site. That's coming up timed out as well.

However, I can connect with:

- my Android phone, when I turn off my WiFi and turn on my data, through that very same Samsung Internet I tried through my WiFi above. I can also get to the web host's site this way.
- my Windows 10 work computer, currently at my house, which is connected to its own network but through my WiFi, using Firefox, Edge, and IE.

(I can't test a ping through work, because I think they block that type of thing. But I get the same results as pinging from home all the same. I also have never been able to connect to the web host's login because it's blocked at work. Maybe they see it as a gaming site or a porn site? Who knows?)

I know these working connections aren't cache issues because I made changes to the site that I can see.

To connect through my WiFi, I've tried, in this order:

- Googling other solutions, but none have worked
- rebooting my modem, but nothing
- rebooting my computer and phone, but still nothing
- going to http://netalyzr.icsi.berkeley.edu/index.html, but I get a 404 from there
- doing a search here on Superuser, finding [Can't access certain web sites - reset router, any ideas?](https://superuser.com/questions/116942/cant-access-certain-web-sites-reset-router-any-ideas), working through that solution, but still nothing
- working through the solution at https://ca.godaddy.com/community/GoDaddy-Web-Hosting/IP-Blocked-from-my-Own-Website/m-p/16134#M421, which might be GoDaddy specific, but I tried it anyway, though I don't have access to my site's CPanel since, as I said, it's blocked over here (but the solution there says my issue is Firewall-related, since my IP address when I ping matches what it says at https://get-site-ip.com/)
- running ipconfig /flushdns (which results in `Successfully flushed the DNS Resolver Cache.`)

This is literally the only site (well, two, with my own site and the web host site) that I've tried to connect to and have been unable to.

Does anyone have a solution for this or can walk me through something I'm missing? Or is the problem on the web host that they, for some reason, blocked some IPs or something? (I've heard this happens sometimes where some IPs get blocked, and I just have to wait it out.)

I should also add that any emails going through my domain (i.e. `****@inagalaxyfarfarawry.com`) aren't reaching me, so that's timing out as well. The last email I got through there came in at 7:07 EST, which is 89 minutes before now. What was I doing? Making dinner downstairs. So, in other words, I wasn't at my computer or anywhere near the site.